# adding Object Properties to DOM and changing value later on

Tags: javascript, object, dom

creating a tic tac toe game..

I have a html table td with an id of "b1"

b1, b2 , b3
b4, b5 , b6
b7, b8 , b9

in my JavaScript, I used the DOM to bring it in

> let b1 = document.getElementById("b1");

here is the thing...
can I make it into an object?

> b1 = { avail: true, mark : "null"; }

I made a loop so if you click on any of the squares, it will change to X or an O by using b1.innerText = "X"..

However, I also want to update the object properties so I can determine the winner (by if b1 + b2 + b3 = "XXX" ) and update the avail so you can't click on it again...

when I try to update the value's in a loop it won't work..

```
const allBoxes = [b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9];

for (let b of allBoxes){
    b.addEventListener("click", function changeAvail(){
        b.innerText = "X";
        b.mark = "X";
        b.avail = false;
    })
};
```

please help.. i've been staring at my screen for a very long time

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. just `setAttribute`.

```js
var b1 = document.getElementById("b1");
var b2 = document.getElementById("b2");
const allBoxes = [b1, b2];

for (let b of allBoxes) {
  b.addEventListener("click", function changeAvail() {
    b.innerText = "X";
    b.setAttribute("mark", "X");
    b.setAttribute("avail", false);

    console.log(b1.getAttribute("mark"));
  })
};
```

```html
<div id="b1">click</div>
<div id="b2">click</div>
```

Comment: thank you! moving in the right direction!